# Not able to include js files in html file on standalone java application

Tags: javascript, html, file, include

Hi I am working on standalone java application running on some port number.
I am trying create UI with HTML where it includes some external js files.

I have included  those files in header tag as below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

But it always gives the error message as "Filed to load resource:the server responded with status code of 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more clarity on the platform? Is it Spring?

Comment: where is the script in this line <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

Comment: your file does not exist at the specified path, you should specify the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pathing issue to me.

What is the relative location of your "js" directory from the calling page in your file system?

Comment: Yes Benjamin, It was only path issue.